# Advanced custom fields - woocommerce - show fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, echo, advanced-custom-fields

I am struggling to show a couple of fields created with ACF on Woocommerce single product page.

I've created a couple of fields to show the pricing table and I would like to show this table just above the add to cart button.

Currently, I have the following code in place:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_acf_field_above_price', 30 );

function display_acf_field_above_price() {
  echo '<div id="price-table">';
  echo '<b>Price Table:</b>';
  echo '<p><span>1 Week</span>' . get_field('1_week') . '</p>';
  echo '<p><span>1 Month</span>' . get_field('1_month') . '</p>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

I get the price table, but now, how can I display the data in more of a table, so there is a gap between the label and the value?

Currently, my output shows like this:

```
1 Week$10
1 Month$30
```

How can I some space in between the label and the value to make it look more like a table?

```
1 Week        $10
1 Month       $30
```

And also, how do I show the field only if it's not empty?

I can see how it's done in the template with php, so for example:

```
<?php if( get_field('county') ) { ?>
    <?php echo get_field('county') . ' County' ; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

But how can I get this `if` statement into my setup with the echos?

Comment: You can use a bootstrap table to make it look pretty :) 
  You'd have to adjust your markup according to this though https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/  Otherwise just add some CSS to create a right margin on the span tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'display_acf_field_above_price', 30 );

function display_acf_field_above_price() {

    if(!empty(get_field('1_month'))){

         echo '<div id="price-table">';
         echo '<b>Price Table:</b>';
         echo '<p><span style="padding-left:10%">1 Week</span>' . get_field('1_week') . '</p>';
         echo '<p><span style="padding-left:10%">1 Month</span>' . get_field('1_month') . '</p>';
         echo '</div>';
      }
 }
```

use an if statement to check if `empty`

put inline padding to override any css